# Receiving values from channels in Go

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Why doesn't the last result returned from `go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)`(the second one) be assigned to `x`?
The two `<-c`s confuse me.
This code is from [A Tour of Go - [Channels]](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(s []int, c chan int) {   // int is the return value type
  sum := 0
  for _, v := range s {
    sum += v
  }
  c <- sum // Sends sum to c
}

func main() {
  s := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

  c := make(chan int)
  go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
  go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)

  x, y := <-c, <-c                 // receive from c

  fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. This example is confusing even for experienced developers. As @eugenioy correctly mentioned below, the order of the assignments is not guaranteed, and this stuff works only because we are summing the values, but the latter is not an excuse, it’s kinda “dirty hack”. Let’s imagine, another developer will be working with this code and going to replace sum with subtraction. Huh? The result is totally undetermined! DO NOT USE THIS CODE, this a potential cause of the floating bugs and side effects!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this line?

```
x, y := <-c, <-c
```

That's a "tuple assignment".

In this case, it would be equivalent to doing:

```
x := <-c
y := <-c
```

So the second value read from `c` would be assigned to `y`.

You can read more about it here:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments

About the order in which the values are actually written to `c`, since two independent goroutines are being triggered here:

```
go sum(s[:len(s)/2], c)
go sum(s[len(s)/2:], c)
```

The order in which they end up processing and writing to `c` is not "guaranteed", so you can expect either one of the values be assigned to `x` and `y` in different runs.

Since the values are being added to calculate the final result, this is not a problem in this case.